# How to know if a script is running in Spyder or any other Python IDE?

Tags: python, task

I can find that spyder.exe is open based on its pid from tasklist, but is there a way to find if the application is idle or any operation such a script is being run inside Spyder or any other Python IDE

Comment: In Spyder you can tell whether a script is running by looking at the small square in the top right of the console window. If a script is running its red, else its grey.

Comment: I meant to find it in a programming it way like from a console, not manually looking  at the IDE and see if its running or not

Answer (score 3):

There are many `SPY_*` environment variables that you can check.

```
if 'SPY_PYTHONPATH' in os.environ:
    # running inside spyder!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q: How check if spyder is running

## A:

```py
def check_spyder():
    try: # fails when not ipython
        ip_name = get_ipython().__class__.__name__
    except: ip_name = -1
    is_spyder = ip_name == 'SpyderShell'
    return is_spyder
```